# How to get a Component in Tridion using Core Service?

Tags: core-service, sdl-tridion

Am new to Tridion Core Service, can someone help me with the sample code to read and get the Component from Tridion using Core Service?

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to Tridion

Core Service is a .Net web service API, allows you to interact with the CMS from another machine than the CMS server itself and before jumping on writing CURD operation using Tridion Core service I would recommend to you , please go through to SDL documentation and learn about Tridion Core Service ,there you will code snippets as well that will help you in writing CRUD operation using Core service

**About Core Service** https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2/GUID-9E83FE0C-F650-451F-BEB3-7960A4925D90

**READ operation**  https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2/GUID-973CC313-C411-4737-8263-F04D4378331C

Comment: sample code for getting component ?

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to check out the 'Core Service Recipies' section of the Tridion Cookbook here: https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/CookbookDocumentation

There are some excellent examples in there to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You can read all components using the core service client,

```
static void RetrievingItems(CoreServiceClient client)
{
    var filterdata = new RepositoryItemsFilterData();
    filterdata.Recursive = true;
    filterdata.ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Component };

    XElement resultxml = client.GetListXml(_publicationId, filterdata);
    if (resultxml != null)
    {
        foreach (var component in resultxml.Elements())
        {
            var compData = (ComponentData)client.Read(component.Attribute("ID").Value, 
                                                      new ReadOptions());
            //Do whatever you want with componnetData
        }
    }
}
```